# 12.04LTS -> 14.04LTS; Dist-upgrade failed; postgresql; removal blacklist

Tags: 12.04, upgrade, postgresql, blacklist

I'm trying to upgrade a server from 12.04LTS to 14.04LTS, but it consistently fails with:

```
The package ... is in the removal blacklist. 

This can be caused by: 

* Upgrading to a pre-release version of Ubuntu 
* Running the current pre-release version of Ubuntu 
* Unofficial software packages not provided by Ubuntu 

If none of this applies, then please report this bug using the 
command 'ubuntu-bug ubuntu-release-upgrader-core' in a terminal.
```

Looking in the log file, I see:

```
ERROR Dist-upgrade failed: 'The package 'postgresql-8.3'
is marked for removal but it is in the removal blacklist.'
```

However I believe postgresql is no longer present on the machine.
I've done:

```
sudo apt-get remove postgresql
sudo apt-get remove postgresql-contrib-8.3
sudo apt-get purge postgresql
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

I've deleted all the files in:

```
/etc/postgresql
/usr/lib/postgresql
/usr/share/postgresql
```

running the remove/purge again gives:

```
sudo apt-get purge postgresql
```

`do-release-upgrade` still fails the same way.

Can anyone advise, please?

Comment: ... but you didn't remove `postgresql-8.3` ?

Comment: Hm, I'd thought "remove postgresql" had done that, but you're right, it hasn't.  It presently thinks it's there and up-to-date, gives an error if I try to remove it, won't --fix-errors, and won't reinstall because it says it can't download it.

Comment: The error I get from apt-get remove boils down to this: "E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)", which I've tried finding in the forum. I seem to have fixed it. Answer to follow.

Answer (score 1):

I edited the file: `/var/lib/dpkg/status` and removed the block relating to the package, e.g.:

```
Package: postgresql-8.3.....
```

onwards to the next blank line.

Comment: Much better to use `dpkg` to un-hold the package, rather than editing the status file directly.

Comment: That's very reasonable, though I couldn't get dpkg to do anything. It too just aborted with an error.  The package wasn't being held; the various tools weren't running to completion.   Thanks for the observation, though, as it's likely a better solution for others.